# How to use clipping mask and difference together in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

Basically I used a clipping mask to cut out some letters in my gradient, then followed the steps in [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30065/how-to-remove-a-path-from-other-paths/30086#30086) but can't get the same result

Here is my lettering after clipping with a path on a raster image:
[image]

Then I apply all the steps from the thread I mentioned above. But instead of getting the desired result of making the holes in the letters transparent, my full gradient PNG is restored and the holes become transparent AND I lose my lettering outline, so basically, I just have holes in my gradient PNG and not letter shapes... Like this result:
[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you obtain your gradient via a PNG and not via the gradient feature inherent to SVGs?

Comment: While Inkscape can only use difference and other boolean operations on one path at a time, there is a very useful extension for multiple path operations http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20762
Other relevant workflows are also discussed there

Comment: Here is a better link https://github.com/Moini/inkscape-extensions-multi-bool

Comment: Thanks @johnp that explains why I was unable to get this to work in inkscape. Since asking this question I've started using Illustrator and it's much easier to get the desired results.

Comment: What does your clipping object look like? It should work if you put the text object above the image, the just do your object, clip, set.

Answer (score 2):

If you are drawing these letters by hand, then try the following technique:

1. The inside of the letter (the counter) needs to be cut out, creating a single combined path.
2. To do that, select both outer path and inner counter and click `Path` > `Difference` to make each letter with a counter cut out. Each letter will now be a single combined path.
3. Once finished, select all the letters, and click `Path` > `Combine` to make all the letter forms into a single combined path.
4. Move the text over a raster image.
5. Select both raster image and text, and click Object > Clip > Set.

[image: Illustrated steps to create clipping path from hand drawn letters]

If you are attempting to do this instead with something you typed using the Text tool, all you need to do is place the text box over the raster image. Select both text and image, and click `Object` > `Clip` > `Set`. There is no need to turn the text into outlines in Inkscape 0.92. Using text as a clipping path converts the text to outlines anyway.

Comment: Do I understand correctly from this that in Inkscape, unlike in Illustrator, a path does *not* have to either have a start and an end or be a single closed path?

Comment: No. A path needs a start or an end, and you can have single or closed paths - in this regard inkscape is little different than illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

- First make the letters with the necessary cutouts (use *Path - difference*).
- Put them on top of the image .
- Clipping.